# Compare files in folders of local machine and remote server

Tags: files, directory, diff

I want to compare and note the files that are different in a folder of my local machine with a folder on remote server. I want to check all subfolders within this folder as well. But not copy from one machine to other. How can I do this. I know about diff command but I am not sure if it can be used with remote servers as well.

Answer (score 1):

With `rsync -n`:

```
-n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made
```

Comment: I tried rsync -n -vrc . hostname:id:/path/ But this command displays hidden folders and files common in both are also displayed. I want to see files which are different in two machines.